# read only .txt files from directory which has subfolders too

Tags: c++

I am trying to read only .txt files from directory.
I am not using arrays.
I am using `opendir()` to open my directory.
`d->d_name` lists all my files and also subfolders.
I want to read only `.txt` but not the subfolders.

please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28VS.85%29.aspx) for this?

Comment: That would depend on which platform he is programming. the opendir/readdir functions are somewhat more portable.

Comment: I am actually asking just to make sure that he is aware of the existence of this other two methods that are quite straightforward if he is developing just for Windows. If he needs portability then I agree with you :).

Answer (score 1):

Well, something like:

- call opendir() to open the directory
- in a loop, call [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) to read each entry
- for each entry, examine the name to see if the last 4 characters are ".txt"
- if they are, do something
- at the end, call closedir to close the directory

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) function to determine the type of file your `struct dirent` represents.

```
struct stat sb;
int rc = stat(filename, &sb);
// error handling if stat failed
if (S_ISREG(sb.st_mode)) {
 // it's a regular file, process it
} else {
 // it's not a regular file, skip it
}
```

Read the man pages for details. Also take care that the filename in `d_name` does not contain the directory part. If you're in a different directory than what you `opendir`'d, you'll need to prepend the directory name (and a directory separator if required).

For a C++ alternative, please see [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You could try put the filenames into a simple structure (string array or vector for example), then pass a reference to that structure to a function that prunes names that don't use the .txt extension

in the function, look at each filename (a for loop would be handy), and use the find function in the String library to see if the last four characters are == to .txt.   You can reset the position of to start searching the string to string_name.length - 4 so that you're only comparing the last few characters.

Cplusplus.com is a great reference for things like the String library: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: Actually, @Riccardo Tramma 's suggestion below is better, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on a Linux/Posix system, you can use **scandir(...)**. You can find the details on the manual page, but in short, you have to provide a filter function that takes a **dirent** pointer as argument, and returns non-zero if the entry is to be included (in your case, you would check for the name ending in .txt, and possibly the file type in the dirent struct).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dir;

    struct dirent *entry;

    int pos;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <directory>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((dir = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
    {
        perror("opendir");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (entry->d_type != DT_REG)
            continue;

        pos = strlen(entry->d_name) - 4;

        if (! strcmp(&entry->d_name[pos], ".txt"))
        {
            printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
        }
    }

    if (closedir(dir) == -1)
    {
        perror("closedir");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```